# Complex Double Variable Returns (NaN) when using Horner's Method for evaluating Polynomials

Tags: c++, nan, complex-numbers

We were asked to evaluate a given polynomial at identified roots using Horner's Method. So I have this function called **useHorner()**

```
complex <long double> useHorner (vector<long double> coeff, complex<long double> x)
{
  //Evaluating polynomial at identified roots using Horner's Method
  complex<long double> answer=coeff[0]; 
  for(int i = 1; i<coeff.size(); i++)
  {
     answer = answer*x+coeff[i]; 
  }
  return answer;
}
```

• The variable **coeff** is a long double vector that contains the numerical coefficients of the polynomial. For example: 
Given a polynomial =  **1**(x ^ 3) **-13**( x ) **-12** 
The variable **coeff** will contain **[1, 0, -13, -12]** 
 
*(note that the coefficients are arranged from coefficient with the 
highest power to the coefficient with the least power)*

• The variable **x** is a complex long double which contains the complex roots that we're trying to evaluate. One root for the polynomial above would be 
(1.0000, 0.0000) where **1.0000** is the real root and **0.000** is the imaginary root.

---

Below is a reproducible code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

using namespace std; 

complex <long double> useHorner (vector<long double> coeff, complex<long double> x); 



int main()
{
    //numerical coefficients of the polynomial with increasing power
    // POLYNOMIAL 1(x ^ 3) -13( x ) -12
    vector <long double> coeffForEval{1, 0, -13, -12}; 

    long double roots[coeffForEval.size()-1][2]; 

    roots[0][0] = -1; 
    roots[0][1] = 0; 

    roots[1][0] = 4;    
    roots[1][1] = 0; 

    roots[2][0] = -3; 
    roots[2][1] =  0; 



    cout << endl << "Evaluating polynomial at identified roots: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<coeffForEval.size()-1; i++)
    {
        complex<long double> x(roots[i][0],roots[i][1]); 
        cout << "f(" << roots[i][0] << ", " << roots[i][1] << ") = " 
        << (useHorner(coeffForEval, x)) << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}


complex <long double> useHorner (vector<long double> coeff, complex<long double> x)
{
  //Evaluating polynomial at identified roots using Horner's Method
  complex<long double> answer(0); 
  for(int i = 0; i<coeff.size(); i++)
  {
     answer = answer*x+coeff[i]; 
  }
  return answer;
}
```

---

Evaluating polynomial at identified roots: 
f(-1, 0) = (0,0) 
f(4, 0) = (0,0)  
f(-3, 0) = (0,0)

---

**[EDIT]** The reproducible code works and returns the correct results, however implementing this in my original file still returns NaN. The only difference is that values inside the **roots** array have different precision :

**[ORIGNAL]**
roots[0][0] = -1.000000 
roots[0][1] = 0.000000 
roots[0][0] = 4.000000 
roots[0][1] = 0.000000 
roots[0][0] = -3.000000 
roots[0][1] = 0.000000 
**[REPRODUCED]**
roots[0][0] = -1 
roots[0][1] = 0 
roots[0][0] = 4
roots[0][1] = 0
roots[0][0] = -3
roots[0][1] = 0

**PROBLEM**: The first evaluation always returns a NaN.

OUTPUT FOR THIS TEST CASE: 
 
**Evaluating polynomial at identified roots:** 
f(-1.000000, 0.000000) = **(nan,nan)**
f(4.000000, 0.000000) = (-0.000000,0.000000) 
f(-3.000000, 0.000000) = (-0.000000,0.000000)

Tracking the output it seems that multiplying **answer by x** in the first iteration causes the output to be NaN. Am I implementing the algorithm correctly?

Comment: Please put all relevant code into one edit, instead of having others piece together your code.  In other words, a [mcve].

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the comment @PaulMcKenzie. The 2nd code snippet just shows how I output the evaluation the 1st code snippet can be reproducible.

Comment: No, the 1st code snippet is not "reproducible". "Reproducible" means that I can compile and run the code and see the problem. Provide a **minimal** **complete** `main` function that shows what is going wrong.

Comment: Oh my bad! Thank you for the correction.

Comment: `long double roots[coeffForEval.size()-1][2];`  -- This is not valid C++.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<long double>> roots(coeffForEval.size() - 1, std::vector<long double>(2));`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you again for replying, I am just curious why ```long double roots[coeffForEval.size()-1][2];``` is not valid? Isn't this just a 2d array declaration?

Comment: In C++, arrays must be declared using a compile-time constant, nor a runtime expression to denote the number of entries.  That's why things such as `std::vector` exists.  Take your code and attempt to compile it using a C++ compiler that adheres to C++ rules, or start your compiler using the options that enforce these rules.